# Image Manipulations on existing images?

Tags: file-uploads

Are you able to apply image manipulations to images that are already uploaded?

When does the image manipulation happen?

For instance you set a selection of manipulations, then you upload 50 images, then change the sizes in the manipulations, how do you have the 50 already uploaded images changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manipulations happen just after a file be uploaded and it can be updated by the [synchronize](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/sync_files.html) button on the [file upload preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html).

You can modify the preferences, but sadly you can't remove old manipulations from the server. If you remove a manipulation, its folder will remain on server and you need to delete it by FTP.